# I get this type of error : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, sklearn-pandas

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
var_mod = ['Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed','Property_Area']
le = LabelEncoder()
for i in var_mod:
    data[i] = le.fit_transform(data[i])
```

I have try this to convert all categorical variables into numeric by encoding the categories. However, I get the following error.

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and some data.  Don't include images of your data.  Edit the question to include text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go through this example : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

and also check this :

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

var_mod = ['Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed','Property_Area']

le.fit(var_mod)

print(le.transform(['Self_Employed','Dependents']))

print(le.transform(['Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed','Property_Area']))
```